# When would IL-written code be faster than C#-written code?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, il

According to [StackOverflow Update: 560M Pageviews A Month, 25 Servers, And It's All About Performance](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html) (perhaps getting its information from [Marco Cecconi The Architecture of Stack Overflow at 29:00](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGi8FT2j8hE#t=1740)),

> Some coding is in IL, not C#.

I am not asking about anything specific to Stack Overflow site, but, generally speaking, when would IL-written code be faster than C#-written code?

My understanding, from reading the posts of Eric Lippert, most of the optimizations in .NET are done when JIT'd:

> We let the jitter team worry about optimizing the heck out of the code when it is actually spit into machine code; that’s the place where you can get real wins. — [What does the optimize switch do?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx)

What sort of optimizations can be made from hand-coded IL?

Comment: Without having any concrete examples, one case would be when you know more about the code/situation than the C# compiler. You could drop unnecessary instructions or cases.

Comment: Not so sure if Marco knows the proper term for what Marc is doing.  Google Relection.Emit

Comment: If you want to know what Marco is talking about, ask Marco.  Likely what is happening here is, as Hans suggests, they are dynamically generating fresh IL and having it jitted on the fly. This is what `dynamic` does behind the scenes -- it generates fresh code like what would have been generated by the C# compiler in the first place had the types been known.